# Compound date statement in Ruby for first weekday after EOM?

Tags: ruby, date

I want to find the first weekday of the month after the 1st which also happens to fall on a weekday in Ruby, something like the following:

```
Min ( DayOfMonth in (2...8) && DayOfWeek in ( monday ... friday )  )
```

How can I state this appropriately?

Comment: Please specify which month(s).

Comment: @CarySwoveland - the next upcoming, although technically it doesn't matter as long as I can pull that specific entry out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can simply start at the second day of the desired month, and keep going to the next day until we find a weekday. This will require 2 increments at most, since the worst case is when day 2 is a Saturday and 3 a Sunday. Our target then would be the 4th day. If Sunday is the 2nd day, our target is 3, and otherwise the desired day is the 2nd of the month. My `first_wday` method returns a `Date` object as well. You can use `.day` to get the day of the month, or `.wday` to get the day of the week on it.

```
require 'date'

def first_wday(date)
  d = Date.new(date.year, date.month, 2)
  d += 1 while d.wday == 6 || d.wday == 0 # Saturday or Sunday
  d
end

(1..12).each do |month|
  date = Date.new(2014, month, 1)
  wday = first_wday(date)
  puts wday.strftime('%9B %Y: %-d (%A)')
end

#   January 2014: 2 (Thursday)
#  February 2014: 3 (Monday)
#     March 2014: 3 (Monday)
#     April 2014: 2 (Wednesday)
#       May 2014: 2 (Friday)
#      June 2014: 2 (Monday)
#      July 2014: 2 (Wednesday)
#    August 2014: 4 (Monday)
# September 2014: 2 (Tuesday)
#   October 2014: 2 (Thursday)
#  November 2014: 3 (Monday)
#  December 2014: 2 (Tuesday)
```

Answer (score 1):

This would be one way of doing it.

**Code**

```
require 'date'

d = Date.today
d = (d-d.day+2).next_month
(d..d+2).find { |i| (1..5).cover?(i.wday) }.strftime("%m-%d-%Y %a")
```

**Explanation**

```
d = Date.today            #=> #<Date:2014-04-28((2456776j,0s,0n),+0s,2299161j)>
d = (d-d.day+2)           #=> #<Date:2014-04-02((2456750j,0s,0n),+0s,2299161j)>
d = d.next_month          #=> #<Date:2014-05-02((2456780j,0s,0n),+0s,2299161j)>

d.month                   #=> 5
d.year                    #=> 2014
d.wday                    #=> 5 (Friday)
```

At least one of the first three days of the month is a weekday, so we need only consider the range `(d..d+2)`. The first value of `(d..d+2)` passed to the block is `d`, so:

```
i = d  #=> #<Date: 2014-05-02 ((2456780j,0s,0n),+0s,2299161j)>
i.wday #=> 5
```

As `Date`'s week starts with 0 on Sunday, the five week days are `1..5`:

```
(1..5).cover?(i.wday) #=> true
(1..5).cover?(4)      #=> true
```

So

```
i.strftime("%m-%d-%Y %a") #=> "05-02-2014 Fri"
```

is returned.